# Opening a new window without an address bar in react js

Tags: reactjs, url, popup

I want to have a pop up window without an address bar.. I saw similar posts but it didn't solve my problem.. However I saw a video on youtube, he entered this on windows command run `chrome.exe --app=https://google.com`. The window output has no address bar. Can someone please teach me how can I put this on my code in react js..

I already build my component here it is:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from '@zendeskgarden/react-buttons';
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import UpdateRepair from './UpdateRepair';
import './App.css';


const RenderInWindow = (props) => {
  const [container, setContainer] = useState(null);
  const newWindow = useRef(window);

  useEffect(() => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    setContainer(div);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (container) {
      newWindow.current = window.open(
        "",
        "Repair Progress",
        "directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200"
      );
      newWindow.current.document.body.appendChild(container);
      const curWindow = newWindow.current;
      return () => curWindow.close();
    }
  }, [container]);

  return container && createPortal(props.children, container);
};

export default function RepairWindowButton(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    console.log(props)
  return (
    <>
            {(open === false) ? 
                <Button className = "button" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Open in new window</Button>
                 :
                <Button className="button" onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>Open in new window</Button>
            }   
      

    {open && <RenderInWindow>
        {props === [] ? null :
            Object.keys(props.buttonData).map((key,i) => (
                <UpdateRepair tryData={props.buttonData[i]} buttonName = "Details" 
                textName = {(parseInt(key, 10) + 1).toString() + '. ' + props.buttonData[i].attributes.RepairOrder} className = "ongoing" />
        ))}
            </RenderInWindow>}
    </>
  );
}
```

As you can see, I already tried the location=no feature. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
let x = new StringBuilder();
x.Append("<script language=\"javascript\">");
x.AppendFormat("eval(\"popUpWindow('{0}',0,0,{1},{2},directories=no)\");", url, 
width, height);
x.Append("</script>");
lblScript.Text = x.ToString();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).